# Дата и время. Угол солнца над горизинтом

Tags: python, python-3.x, время, datetime

Определить угол солнца над горизонтом, зная время суток. Исходные данные: солнце встает на востоке в 6:00, что соответствует углу 0 градусов. В 12:00 солнце в зените, а значит угол = 90 градусов. В 18:00 солнце садится за горизонт и угол равен 180 градусов. В случае, если указано ночное время (раньше 6:00 или позже 18:00), функция должна вернуть фразу "I don't see the sun!".

```
from datetime import datetime 
def sun_angle(time):
    #replace this for solution
    list_fortime=[]   #пустой список для значений 
    dt = datetime.strptime(time, '%H:%M')   #перевод из строки 
    tt=datetime.timetuple(dt)   # struct_time 
    for it in tt:
        list_fortime.append(it) # заполняем новый список 
    if list_fortime[3]>=6 and list_fortime[3]<=18:
        time_1=(list_fortime[3]-6)*15 #1 час= 15 градусов 
        time_2= (str(list_fortime[4])+str(list_fortime[5]) #1 минута 0.25 градуса 
        time_3 = int(time_2) #тут ошибка , возможно с преобразованием типов ,подскажите что не так 
        return time_1+time_3
    else:
        return 'I don\'t see the sun!'

    #return tt
    #if tim[]>=6
    #return time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Example:")
    print(sun_angle("07:00"))

    #These "asserts" using only for self-checking and not necessary for auto-testing
    assert sun_angle("07:00") == 15
    assert sun_angle("01:23") == "I don't see the sun!"
```

подскажите где ошибаюсь и альтернативный способ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы используете что-то уж очень сложное. Несколько структур данных, и прочее. Нужно провести анализ задачи: время должно быть в диапазоне от XXX Минут до YYY минут.
Первое решение

```
def sun_angle(time):
    #replace this for solution
    list_fortime=[]   #пустой список для значений
    dt = datetime.strptime(time, '%H:%M')   #перевод из строки
    #Восход и закат в минутах
    startOfSun=6*60
    endOfSun=18*60
    #переводим время в минуты
    tt=dt.time().hour*60+dt.time().minute
    #Если время в диапазоне, то считаем угол как долю от дуги окружности.
    if tt in range (startOfSun,endOfSun+1):
        return 180*(tt-startOfSun)/(endOfSun-startOfSun)
    else:
        return 'I don\'t see the sun!'
```

И решение с использованием только `datetime`

```
from datetime import datetime
def sun_angle(startSun,endSun,time):
    dt = datetime.strptime(time, '%H:%M')   #перевод из строки
    startOfSun=datetime.strptime(startSun, '%H:%M')   #перевод из строки
    endOfSun=datetime.strptime(endSun, '%H:%M')   #перевод из строки

    #Если время в диапазоне, то считаем угол как долю от дуги окружности.
    if dt>=startOfSun and dt<=endOfSun:
        # переводим время в минуты
        tt = dt.time().hour * 60 + dt.time().minute
        tStart=startOfSun.time().hour * 60 + startOfSun.time().minute
        tEnd = endOfSun.time().hour * 60 + endOfSun.time().minute
        return 180*(tt-tStart)/(tEnd-tStart)
    else:
        return 'I don\'t see the sun!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Example:")
    print(sun_angle("6:00","18:00","12:00"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
from datetime import datetime as DT

def sun_angle(tm):
    dt = DT.strptime(tm, "%H:%M")
    if not (6 <= dt.hour <= 18):
        return "I don't see the sun!"
    # возвращаем число минут начиная с [06:00] умноженное на 0.25
    return ((dt.hour - 6) * 60 + dt.minute) * 0.25
```

Comment: спасибо , но наверно на 15 , а не 60 , я правильно понял?

Comment: @Anthony, насколько я помню в часе все таки 60 минут ;)

Comment: все , понял , вы все в минуты переводили) спасибо !